# t sql everything right of first number in string

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I am using MS SQL Server 2014 and have a string like this:

```
ABC 123 DEF XYZ
```

How do I extract everything right from the numbers onwards, so I would end up with:

```
DEF XYZ
```

The numbers could change and won't always be 123.  I have tried the below to no avail:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ABC 123 DEF XYZ',CHARINDEX('[0-9]%','ABC 123 DEF XYZ')+1,LEN('ABC 123 DEF XYZ'))
```

Comment: "The numbers could change..." -> Does that mean that also the length can change or do you always have a prefix of `ccc nnn`?

Comment: yes, the length could change, but it would be string number string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that the number will always be followed by a space, you could use could use `CHARINDEX`, `PATINDEX` and `STUFF`:

```sql
SELECT V.YourString,
       STUFF(V.YourString,1,CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',V.YourString)),'')
FROM (VALUES('ABC 123 DEF XYZ'))V(YourString);
```